# NSArray of UIImages to video error has distortion in the output

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video, uiimage

I am relatively new to programming and although i am ok with normal functions, i am however completely new to video editing

So i have managed to find some code online to do the jobs shown below:

```
- (void)writeImagesAsMovie:(NSArray *)array {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDirectory, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *saveLocation = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/temp.mov"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:saveLocation]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:saveLocation error:NULL];
}

UIImage *first = [array objectAtIndex:0];

CGSize frameSize = first.size;

NSError *error = nil;
AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveLocation] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];

if(error) {
    NSLog(@"error creating AssetWriter: %@",[error description]);
}
NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:frameSize.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:frameSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];



AVAssetWriterInput *writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                    assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                    outputSettings:videoSettings];

NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:frameSize.width] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey];
[attributes setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:frameSize.height] forKey:(NSString*)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:attributes];

[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

// fixes all errors
writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

//Start a session:
[videoWriter startWriting];

[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[first CGImage]];
BOOL result = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];

if (result == NO) //failes on 3GS, but works on iphone 4
    NSLog(@"failed to append buffer");

if(buffer) {
    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
}



//int reverseSort = NO;
NSArray *newArray = array;



int fps = 10;


int i = 0;
for (UIImage *image in newArray)
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.02];
    if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {

        i++;
        CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, fps);
        CMTime lastTime = CMTimeMake(i, fps);
        CMTime presentTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, frameTime);

        UIImage *imgFrame = image;//[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath] ;
        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[imgFrame CGImage]];
        BOOL result = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:presentTime];

        if (result == NO) //failes on 3GS, but works on iphone 4
        {
            NSLog(@"failed to append buffer");
            NSLog(@"The error is %@", [videoWriter error]);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
        }

        if(buffer) {
            CVBufferRelease(buffer);
        }


    } else {
        NSLog(@"error");
        i--;
    }
}

//Finish the session:
[writerInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter finishWriting];
CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);

NSLog(@"Movie created successfully");
}

- (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image
{


    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

    CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                        CGImageGetHeight(image), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                        &pxbuffer);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                                 CGImageGetHeight(image), 8, 4*CGImageGetWidth(image), rgbColorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));

    //    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(
    //                                                           1, 0, 0, -1, 0, CGImageGetHeight(image)
    //                                                           );
    //    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);



    //    CGAffineTransform flipHorizontal = CGAffineTransformMake(
    //                                                             -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, CGImageGetWidth(image), 0.0
    //                                                             );
    //
    //    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipHorizontal);


    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

But the problem that i am having is that the output of the video is some how corrupted (it does play although it has funny lines shown below:
[image]

I would be so grateful for any help

Many Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have been seeing problems with the H264 video encoding hardware where it can corrupt input that does not match an known aspect ratio. For example, my testing shows that if one video dimension is smaller than 128 pixel, the video will not encode.

What I have seen working is 128x128, 192x128, 240x160, 480x320, and others.

See this [page on aspect ratios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_display_standard)

P.S.
You will likely want to use the `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` since it contains a pixel buffer pool that you can use via `CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer()`. Also, you will want to `assert(adaptor.pixelBufferPool);` after calling `startSessionAtSourceTime` to ensure that your adaptor can write to the writer.

Comment: Very helpful. Can you update the link or share more information regarding the supported aspect ratios? I noticed that although 960x540 is supported, 540x960 is not; are portrait formats generally not supported by h264?

Comment: There is no documentation on this anywhere, I looked. You just have to try it at a specific size and see if it works. You might not get an error code at a specific size, but the hardware could still scramble your image data. H.264 should work with most sizes (assuming both sides are event that is), but the hardware to encode to h.264 includes with iOS is a lot more picky and hard to deal with.

Comment: I have the same issue going on with me. Can you please explain the answer here or direct me to the link?

Comment: Can you please update aspect ratio link? Thank you for useful info. after struggling hours changing the code at the end it is an issue of aspect ratio.